# Find all indexes in my database SQL

Tags: sql, indexing

I need a query which will list all the indexes in my database. Will this simple code work?

```
select * 
from sys.indexes
```

I'm not sure if this is correct or if I need a larger code.

Comment: You could try a bigger font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will actually give you too many objects, as sys.indexes includes HEAPS in addition to nonclustered and clustered indexes. If you do not want HEAPS, go with:

```
select *
from sys.indexes
where name is not null
```